# Get average color(s) of the screen in real time (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, terminal, arduino, light

Is it posible to get average color (or more) of the computer screen in real time on a Mac?

For example, if I'm watching this site it will probably be white. I'm trying to make very simple ambient light with Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Mac developer, so I may be off the mark here, but I doubt Mac OS X provides a method specifically to get the average color of the screen.  What you could do is take a screenshot and resize it down to one pixel using [Core Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Image), which should efficiently (using hardware acceleration where available) calculate the average.

Comment: Hmm didn't think of this. If nothing else will be posible I will try it.

Comment: @ajitam See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147779/how-do-i-release-a-cgimageref-in-ios/12148136#12148136) for a similar approach. It's about four times faster than iterating over pixel data.